# Integrated Security for multiple domains?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to connect to a db with Integrated Security from multiple domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you have to set up the active directory domains to handle a restricted trust.  Then sql server can use the credentials from both domains.